# MySql select using time comparison

Tags: mysql, database

For my project, I need to select rows from this table

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| hardware_type_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| make_type_id     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| year             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| model            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name             | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| warranty         | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

where the warranty is still valid at the time of search. (If warranty is null, then do not select that row)

Basically I need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM hardware WHERE ({now} - warranty) <0; // valid warranty
SELECT * FROM hardware WHERE ({now} - warranty) >0; // invalid warranty
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: WHERE warranty > CURDATE() and < for the other option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Mihai already said

```
SELECT * FROM hardware WHERE warranty <=  CURDATE(); // valid warranty
SELECT * FROM hardware WHERE warranty >  CURDATE() OR warranty IS NULL; // invalid warranty
```

This should work, you can also use NOW() or CURTIME() if it's datetime or a time type

Comment: Thank you! But this doesn't select invalid warranty when the data is null, what's the best way to resolve this ?

Comment: I think I solve this by WHERE warranty <=  CURDATE() OR warranty IS NULL, thank you again.

Comment: @NobleDinasaur Correct, i was assuming you didn't allow the field to be NULL. If you do you add your OR line too it, i'll add it to my answer as well so it's complete

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`DATEDIFF`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) like this:

```
SELECT *, 
       IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(), warranty) > 0, false, true) AS IsWarrantyValid
FROM hardware
```

If `DATEDIFF(NOW(), warranty) > 0` this means that `warranty` is *before* current date, hence it has expired. Thus the `IF` expression returns false in this case.

Comment: Thank you! But I can't use 
WHERE IsWarrantyValid, what's the best way to use the column?

Comment: @NobleDinasaur It depends on what your actual requirement is. Do you want to get only valid warranty records, only not valid, or maybe both along with the info whether the warranty is valid or not? My query addresses the third.

Comment: Dont use IsWarrantyValid. it is not the best way. if you use a function on a field which is use in where MySQL must calculate it for each row before it can compare. So it is a FULL TABLE SCAN and cant use a INDEX and the QUERY will very slow. use EXPLAIN to see this

Comment: @BerndBuffen Yes this is correct. My query just shows how you can just *return* the not valid / valid info in the `SELECT` clause. The `IF` expression is not suitable for a predicate used in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This query didn't get what I initially needed, but this query will be very helpful for displaying on my managing list. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(warranty > (now()-warranty))
then 
select * from hardware where warranty > (now()-warranty)   ;
end if ;
```